# Subclass constructor/definition (absolute beginner)

Tags: java

I am just starting to learn Java-8 and using Netbeans. For now I am just coding to understand but eventually I have personal projects I want to code.

I am trying to understand what am I doing wrong as Netbeans is flagging my code having errors but I think it is simply because I do not fully understand how to create a subclass.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public class Point3d {
    public double point_x=0;
    public double point_y=0;
    public double point_z=0;

    Point3d(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.point_x=x;
        this.point_y=y;
        this.point_z=z;
    }

}

public class Center_of_gravity extends Point3d {

    Center_of_gravity(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.point_x=x;
        this.point_y=y;
        this.point_z=z;
    }

}
```

This is my attempt to define the very basic classes without methods (yet).  As some of the classes I want to create have to be subclasses of other primary classes. I need to understand how it works and be able to successfully code methods and so on.  Once I am able to code classes and subclasses, then I can start writing code.

Comment: You have to pass the variables to base class construtor from derived class using super keyword.

In your derived class constructor use super like this
super(x,y,z);

Comment: BTW Your IDE should write the code for you when you create a sub-class. Try using the IDE to add a constructor to the sub-class.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add parent constructor like:

```
public class Center_of_gravity extends Point3d {
    Center_of_gravity(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        super(x,y,z);
    }
}
```

It will initialize your (x,y,z) how you wrote in Point3d.

If you wish to don't use parent constructor handly, you must to define default parent constructor in Point3d:

```
Point3d() {
    //default empty constructor
}
```

In that case you can write

```
Center_of_gravity(double x, double y, double z)
{
    //any code
}
```

Comment: In your first example where you are using Super(..), how does the compiler knows the class is a Subclass of Point3d ?

Comment: Center_of_gravity extends Point3d - here you define Center_of_gravity to be a child of Point3d

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `super` in your `Center_of_gravity` constructor, so the compiler is trying to insert a call to the no argument constructor of `Point3d`, which doesn't exist. See, e.g. [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).